# There is no interaction when clicking the button

Tags: html, angular, typescript

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hU9g.png)

```
                        <form [formGroup]="signUpForm">
                            <div class="form-group pt-3">
                                <div class="input-field">
                                    <span class="fa fa-user p-2"></span>
                                    <input formControlName="firstName" type="text" placeholder="Ad">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <small
                                *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['fistName'].dirty && signUpForm.hasError('required', 'firstName')"
                                class="text-danger">*Ad gerekli!</small>
                            <div class="form-group pt-3">
                                <div class="input-field">
                                    <span class="fa fa-user p-2"></span>
                                    <input formControlName="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Soyad">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <small
                                *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['lastName'].dirty && signUpForm.hasError('required', 'lastName')"
                                class="text-danger">*Soyad gerekli!</small>
                            <div class="form-group pt-3">
                                <div class="input-field">
                                    <span class="fa fa-envelope p-2"></span>
                                    <input formControlName="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <small
                                *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['email'].dirty && signUpForm.hasError('required', 'email')"
                                class="text-danger">*E-mail gerekli!</small>
                            <div class="form-group pt-3">
                                <div class="input-field">
                                    <span class="fa fa-user p-2"></span>
                                    <input formControlName="userName" type="text" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adı">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <small
                                *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['userName'].dirty && signUpForm.hasError('required', 'userName')"
                                class="text-danger">*Kullanıcı Adı gerekli!</small>
                            <div class="form-group pt-3">
                                <div class="input-field">
                                    <span class="fa fa-lock p-2"></span>
                                    <input formControlName="password" [type]="type" placeholder="Şifre">
                                    <span (click)="hideShowPass()" class="fa {{eyeIcon}}"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <small
                                *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['password'].dirty && signUpForm.hasError('required', 'password')"
                                class="text-danger">*Şifre gerekli!</small>
                            <button type="submit" style="background-color: black; color:white;"
                                class="btn btn-black btn-block mt-4 w-100" (click)="onSignUp()">Kayıt Ol</button>
                            <div class=" text-center pt-4 text-muted">Zaten bir hesabın var mı? <a id="forget"
                                    routerLink="/login">Oturum Aç</a>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

`

This is my angular signup form but when I click the submit "(kayıt ol)" button, there is no interaction and a frame appears around the password section. How can I fix this?  (When you click the Submit button, it should give a warning because there are spaces.)

Comment: I usely work with NgForm, but don't you also have to give the name of the function to the <form submit="OnSignUp()"> tag? Try that please

Comment: <form submit="onSignUp()" [formGroup]="signUpForm"> same error persists when i write like this (I posted the error I got at the top.)

Comment: The error indicates that something in your template is undefined, and you're trying to access the `dirty` property of it. This issue occurs on line 18 of the template file. Likely the issue lies in how you set up your form. If it is created in `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit` (anywhere outside the constructor or as a property) the form doesn't exist when the view is created. You can either move your form declaration or use optional chaining `signUpForm.controls['firstName']?.dirty`. ... or it might just be because you've got a typo in your template (`fistName` vs `firstName`) :)

Comment: Oh thank you very much, I never realized that I wrote fist instead of first, all the problem is solved, thank you very much :)